# Получение данных из формы в переменную

Tags: html, post, golang, golang-gin

Из HTML-формы нужно получить данные, вот из такой конструкции:

```
<select class="dropdown-toggle user_role" name="user_role" form="idForm" method="post">
    {{range $type := .cook.TypeCook }}
        <option>{{$type}}</option>
    {{end}}
</select>
```

В коде Go не понимаю как получить данные:

```
r.POST("/main/:type/", func(c *gin.Context) {
    var st string
    if c.Bind(st) == nil{
        println(st)
    }
})
```

Answer (score 4):

В HTML надо указать в `value` значение, по какому параметру будете выбирать.

Например:

```
<form action="/main/type-example/" method="POST">
    <select name="user_role">
        {{range $type := .cook.TypeCook }}
            <option value="{{$type}}">{{$type}}</option>
        {{end}}
    </select>
</form>
```

А в Go берёте из формы:

```
r.POST("/main/:type/", func(c *gin.Context){
    t := c.PostForm("user_role")
})
```